# Estimating the bit operations using big O notation

Tags: time-complexity

Using big- O  notation estimate in terms  of a simple function of $ n $ the number of  bit  operations required to compute $3^n$  in binary.

I need some help with the above question. The number of bit operations required to multiply two k- bit numbers is $O(k^2)$.
In the first step I am multiplying two 2-bit numbers, in the 2nd step a 4-bit and a 2-bit number and so on.
So the total bit operations will be I feel
$O(k^2) + O(k^2 * k) +.... + O(k^{n-1} * k)
\,\,with \,\, k \,= 2 $

How will the above sum be estimated as a function of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems. First, the time complexity of multiplying two k-bit numbers is much less than O(k^2). More like O(k log k). Since this is an important open research problem, you usually assume it is O(M(k)) for some function M and use that further.

Second, you are not multiplying two k bit numbers. You are multiplying one k-bit number by 3, which is done easily in O(k). This would get you a total of O(n^2).

Third, that’s not a clever method to calculate $3^n$. Much better is repeated squaring/multiplying. For example to calculate $3^{100}$: Start with 3, square, multiply by 3, square, square, square, multiply by 3, square, square. Since the number of bits starts small and doubles every time, this works in O(M(n)).

Comment: we are not multiplying two 2-bit numbers but one 2-bit number by 3..this is not clear to me. We are performing the multiplication in binary. So when I do 3 times 3 how is it not multiplying two 2-bit numbers? Please explain this a little bit more.

Comment: 3x3 = 2 x 2 bit. 9x3 = 4 x 2 bit. 27x3 = 5 x 2 bit. 81x3 = 7 x 2 bit etc. 3^99 is about 160 bits.